# Objective-C: Is there an -invoke on blocks that takes parameters?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

As you may be aware, blocks take `-invoke`:

```
void(^foo)() = ^{
    NSLog(@"Do stuff");
};

[foo invoke];  // Logs 'Do stuff'
```

I would like to do the following:

```
void(^bar)(int) = ^(int k) {
     NSLog(@"%d", k);
};

[bar invokeWithParameters:7];   // Want it to log '7', but no such instance method
```

The ordinary argument-less `-invoke` works on `bar`, but it prints a nonsense value.

I can't find a direct message of this kind I can send to a block, nor can I find the original documentation that would describe how blocks take `-invoke`.
Is there a list of messages accepted by blocks?

(Yes, I have tried to use `class_copyMethodList` to extract a list of methods from the runtime; there appear to be none.)

**Edit:** Yes, I'm also aware of invoking the block the usual way (`bar(7)`;). What I'm really after is a selector for a method I can feed into library code that doesn't take blocks (per-se).

Comment: Stab in the dark, won't post as answer because I'm not sure.

I am always very wary of using primitives in Obj-C. So maybe this will work, maybe not. So, instead of int, try using NSInteger. (Even I'm not convinced this is the problem, but I've seen stranger things)

Comment: Um. NSInteger *is* a primitive type (NSNumber is not), and that has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A blocks very definition is the sum total of "messages" that the block can receive, in terms of the calling parameters/ABI.

This is for a couple of reasons:

First, a block is not a function and a block pointer is not a function pointer.  They cannot be used interchangeably.

Secondly, the C ABI is such that you *have* to have a declaration of the function begin called when the call site is being compiled if the parameters are to be encoded correctly.

The alternative is to use something like NSInvocation, which allows the arguments to be encoded individually, but even that still requires full C ABI knowledge for each individual argument.

Ultimately, if you can compile a call site that has all the parameters, be it an Objective-C method or a function call, to the fidelity necessary to make the compiler happy, you can convert that call site into a call to the block.

I.e. unless you clarify your question a bit, what you are asking for is either already supported or nigh impossible due to the vagaries of the C ABI.

Comment: Well, here's how I originally thought about the situation. The compiler emits a custom struct for each block, depending on the number of parameters and captured variables. Since the compiler already knows the function signature of the block, it could emit code in the block's class to respond to a selector that can take the appropriate series of arguments.

Comment: The compiler doing so wouldn't gain you anything, though.  A call site still has to have all of the type information and a reference to the block to be able to compile a call.  I.e. Exactly what is needed for the block call itself.

Answer (score 11):

You can invoke it like a function:

```
bar(7);
```

There's even an example in the documentation that uses exactly the same signature. See [Declaring and Using a Block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1).

The best reference on the behavior of blocks is the [Block Language Specification](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libclosure/libclosure-53/BlockSpec.rtf)(RTF) document. This mentions certain methods that are supported (copy, retain, etc.) but nothing about an `-invoke` method.

Comment: An Apple engineer [confirms](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/123602?tstart=0) that this is a private method.